# Photoshop created button won't fill entire background of Android button widget

Tags: android, image, button, photoshop

I have created a shiny button in photoshop and now wish to use it for the background of a button on an android layout. Every time I change the buttons buttons background property it inserts the button but it does not fill the entire background but instead seems to push the boundaries of the button away from it as if there were huge amounts of padding! I have not altered the buttons padding properties either! I have previously been successful in filling the buttons entire background with buttons already created that I downloaded from the internet but I dont know if the were created in photoshop......however I did resize these buttons in photoshop and then successfully use them. Please see the [image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCNcU.png) and notice the blue outline of the button whose background I am trying to fill! Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: Thanks mate tried that and no joy. I ended up print screening the image, cropping it down in paint, throwing the image back into photoshop, magic erasing its background (which i cropped to ensure it was small). Then saving for web and devices. My problem was my image from photoshop was taking the entire pallete background with it...even though it was transparent it was still there and pushing out the borders of my button. Got round it in an unorthadox way but will now have to learn how to get rid of pallete bachground when exporting images from photoshop! Thanks again!!